# How to strip HTML tags from a dropdown option list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

Given a dropdown list that is generated and escapes html tags server-side, I need to strip (not necessarily escape) HTML tags- I need the input to stay intact because the actual HTML tags are stored that way in the database. I just need the dropdown options to not display the HTML tags in the browser. Any help would be appreciated- and I would prefer to do this in JavaScript or jQuery. Thank you.

```
<option value="4658">03/26/20 - &lt;a id=&quot;ont3&quot;&gt;Alpha Omega Suites&lt;br&gt;3333 Makers Circle&lt;br&gt;Anytown, CA&lt;br&gt;99999&lt;/a&gt;</option>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Comment: Another idea is to strip tags server-side and store the stripped versions in a separate database column. Then you can keep the original string, but output the stripped version in select lists.